# How to select something when doing searching

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight the row in red when the selection criteria met , but I found that in the whole process of searching the program didn't select any cell , what should I do?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim celltxt As String
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim aMonthFromNow As Date

    For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        aMonthFromNow = DateAdd("m", 1, Now)

        If Month(cell) = Month(aMonthFromNow) And Day(cell) = Day(aMonthFromNow) Then
            MsgBox "cc 1 month notice at " & cell.Address
        End If
    Next

    For Each cell In Range("M1:M" & Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cell = DateAdd("m", 2, Left(Now, 10)) Then
            MsgBox "ee 2 months notice at " & cell.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to highlight the row in red when the selection crteria met

You want to highight in red but you are actually showing the cell in a `MsgBox`

Use this to highlight the row in `RED`

```
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: OH REALLY THANKS I WANNA DO BOTH THINGS , YOU HELP ME ALOT